# Can't deploy React App with gh-pages. "Remote url mismatch."

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a react app with gh-pages for the first time and I keep hitting this same problem when I run deploy.

```
> cvproj@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

Remote url mismatch.  Got "/home/savannaha/Desktop/the_odin_project/cvproj/cvproj/git@github.com:savwiley/cvproject.git" but expected "git@github.com:savwiley/cvproject.git" in /home/savannaha/Desktop/the_odin_project/cvproj/cvproj/node_modules/.cache/gh-pages/git@github.com!savwiley!cvproject.git.  Try running the `gh-pages-clean` script first.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/savannaha/Desktop/the_odin_project/cvproj/cvproj
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c gh-pages -d build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/savannaha/.npm/_logs/2021-03-19T01_29_49_032Z-debug.log
```

The first thing I did was run *gh-pages-clean* with node but it doesn't do anything. I've manually deleted the .cache folder in the node_modules, deleted the node_modules folder, uninstalled/reinstalled gh-pages, updated all of the programs I'm using, created a whole new repo, tried to use yarn instead of npm, made sure I didn't have gh-pages installed globally, emptied my computer's .cache folder, and it still comes back with this error.

When I really dug into the code to try to backtrack the problem, I narrowed it down to it coming back with the wrong url when it clones the repo, but I don't know how to fix it.

I originally followed [this article](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-into-github-pages-b2c96292b18e) on how to use gh-pages. Parts of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cvproj",
  "homepage": "http://savwiley.github.io/cvproj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
}
```

Kind of feel like whatever I'm doing wrong is something really obvious since I was unable to find anyone else with this problem online, unless I just totally missed them. If you know anything, I'd love some help. And if you want to see anything else I didn't think about sharing, just ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, I finally resolved the issue with some awesome help.

First, make sure the issue is an isolated one by deploying a bare bones app with nothing added or installed. I went ahead and added everything step-by-step and redeployed every time with no problems, but my older repos still came back with the error.

If you want to deploy your original app:

- Make sure all of your dependencies and programs are up to date. Git was tricky because the terminal *said* it was when it wasn't so check [on their site](https://git-scm.com/downloads). If you're using Ubuntu, [this is a good how-to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170831).
- Delete the build folder if it already added one.
- Delete the node_modules > .cache > gh-pages folder
- Make sure everything is pushed to github.
- Make sure your repo doesn't have a github pages site running already.
- Run deploy.

I have *no idea why* but it worked for me. It really feels like I did all of this already but maybe I didn't at the same time? Anyway, I hope no one else has this frustrating problem, but I'll leave this solution here in case it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I added the command 'gh-pages-clean' in front of the deploy script. Seemed to fix the issue.

So in your scripts section in the package.json file, replace
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
with
"deploy": "gh-pages-clean gh-pages -d build",

then I changed it back to deploy the changes to gh pages